# RubyMine highlights some lines of just created working projects as errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am new in Ruby on Rails, and as I came from Java world and was working in IntelliJ Idea, I stared to use RubyMine for RoR development.

I have generated new project and opened it in RubyMine. Everything compiles and works fine but RubyMine highlights some lines as errors (but actually there are no errors).

For example code from application_controller.rb

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

semicolon after 'with' is highlighted as error and hind says 'Expected: ; or end of line'

Similar error highlights are in a lot of places in project

I guess may be there are some problems with different Ruby and Rails versions? Or RubyMine don't have support for some kind of new syntax?

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

Rails 4.0.1

Comment: Go to File -> Settings -> 'Ruby SDK and gems', and check that you have a ruby 2.0 SDK, with language level 1.9

Comment: i have language level 1.8. and field is disabled. I can't change it

Comment: I have chosen another ruby installation and it changed to 1.9.

Comment: Did that solve the highlight problem ? it should, the syntax `with: :exception` has been introduced with ruby 1.9; with previous version of ruby, the syntax was ':with => :exception' (which is also acceptable in 1.9)

Answer (score 3):

RubyMine 5 couldn't do `with:`, and RubyMine 6 can.

A major tip: If you come from Java-land, you will find that static analysis of dynamic languages is hit-or-miss. (It needn't be, per http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/05/dynamic_languages_vs_editors.html , but it is!) You will learn how to disregard some of the details that RubyMine complains about.

For example, you should prefer `'single quotes'` without a compelling technical need for `"double quotes"`. But tests should use literate strings with double quotes, such as `scenario "I do not like RubyMine lint" do`. That's just an edit away from `scenario "I don't like RubyMine's lint" do`, so all such literate strings should start with double quotes. But RubyMine dutifully flags them.

Comment: I'm using RM 7, but I'm having this issue with attr_accessor:foo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With later RubyMine versions on Mac:

Go to Preferences -> 'Language & Frameworks' -> 'Ruby SDK and Gems', and change to Ruby 2.0 SDK

Restart and it should work

Comment: be careful with cut and paste of same answer in multiple answers to questions. They tend to get deleted.